# How to make numpy array column sum up to 1

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, pagerank

I am working on building a transition matrix for implementing the PageRank algorithm. How could I use numpy to make sure that the columns add up to one.

For example:

```
1 1 1   
1 1 1  
1 1 1
```

should be normalized to be

```
.33 .33 .33  
.33 .33 .33  
.33 .33 .33
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Divide the elements of each column by their column-summations -

```
a/a.sum(axis=0,keepdims=1) # or simply : a/a.sum(0)
```

For making the row-summations unity, change the axis input -

```
a/a.sum(axis=1,keepdims=1)
```

Sample run -

```
In [78]: a = np.random.rand(4,5)

In [79]: a
Out[79]: 
array([[ 0.37,  0.74,  0.36,  0.41,  0.44],
       [ 0.51,  0.86,  0.91,  0.03,  0.76],
       [ 0.56,  0.46,  0.01,  0.86,  0.38],
       [ 0.72,  0.66,  0.56,  0.84,  0.69]])

In [80]: b = a/a.sum(axis=0,keepdims=1)

In [81]: b.sum(0) # Verify
Out[81]: array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.])
```

To make sure it works on `int` arrays as well for Python 2.x, use `from __future__ import division` or use [`np.true_divide`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.true_divide.html).

---

**For columns adding upto `0`**

For columns that add upto `0`, assuming that we are okay with keeping them as they are, we can set the summations to `1`, rather than divide by `0`, like so -

```
sums = a.sum(axis=0,keepdims=1); 
sums[sums==0] = 1
out = a/sums
```

Comment: Fails for columns with sum zero.

Comment: @grofte As the question states we need to make the output such that the sum for each col adds upto 1. So, for columns that adds upto exactly `0`, I don't see how we can convert them to  add upto `1`.

Comment: But the OP is making a PageRank implementation. You can have nodes that don't point to anything. When this happens then they need 1/n in each value of the column.

Comment: @grofte So, are you saying that columns that add upto `0`, should stay as such. i.e. add upto `0` and not worry about adding upto `1`?. Think OP should have qualified on that.

Comment: OK. Here's an article about PageRank: https://www.rose-hulman.edu/~bryan/googleFinalVersionFixed.pdf

Comment: @grofte Seems like an informative piece, though I don't have time to read. Made edits in this post to take care of that case and not change column elements.

Answer (score -2):

```
for i in range(len(A[0])):
    col_sum = A[:, i].sum()
    if col_sum != 0:
        A[:, i] = A[:, i]/col_sum
    else: 
        pass
```

The `for loop` is a bit sloppy and I'm sure there's a much more elegant way but it works.
Replace `pass` with `A[:, i] = 1/len(A[0])` to eliminate dangling nodes and make the matrix column stocastic.